# Preg_replace multiple bbcodes correctly

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, bbcode

Currenlty I'm creating a bbCodes function to replace all bbCodes by their corresponding HTML codes within a text. My code works like this atm:

```
public function bbCodes($text) {

    global $bb_codes;

    $text = preg_replace(array_keys($bb_codes), array_values($bb_codes), $text);

    return $text;

}
```

where $bb_codes looks like this:

```
$bb_codes = array(
            "/\[b\](.*)\[\/b\]/is" => "<b>$1</b>",
            "/\[u\](.*)\[\/u\]/" => "<u>$1</u>",
            "/\[i\](.*)\[\/u\]/" => "<i>$1</i>",
            "/\[d\](.*)\[\/d\]/" => "<del>$1</del>",
            "/\[url=(.*)\](.*)\[\/url\]/" => "<a href='$1'>$2</a>"
              );
```

It's working when each bbcode is only used once, e.g.:

```
[b]this text is bold[/b]
[i]this text is italic[/i]
etc..
```

But as soon as I use one bbcode tag multiple times it gets messed up:

```
   [b]this text is bold[/b]
   [i]this text is italic[/i]
   [b]this text is bold too[/b]
```

It will see the first [b] tag and look for another [/b] tag but it takes the last one instead of the first one it encounters (in the above example all the text will be bold and the first [b] and last [/b] will be replaced only). Does anyone know what I've done wrong and how I can fix this?

Thanks in advanced!

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use non greedy wildcard, instead of all the `.*` write `.*?`.

Comment: You might want to elaborate on that but it's the correct answer.

Comment: Didn't know it could be that simple, thanks that fixed it. Still not quite sure what it stands for but I'll look it up. edit: found it and I understand the use of it, exactly the solution for my problem.

Comment: No, the correct answer is dis-recommending regex and recommending [a proper parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php) instead.

Comment: @Tomalak touche... (Go with the proper parser)

Comment: What are the cons of using regex?

Comment: @Skyfe: Regex is not able to parse nested structures such as BBcode (or HTML or XML or any other kind of complex language). Regex can parse *regular* languages (hence the name). BBcode is not a regular language. Trying to handle it with regex can fail at best and result in a security hole in in your application at worst. *Even more so* if you are so new to regex that `.*?` was unknown to you. Since there already is a BBcode parser available for PHP, invest your some and learn how it works; you will be a lot better of in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Why you're not using BBCode Parser ? 
Look at [NBBC](http://nbbc.sourceforge.net/) Parser.

To install it just put it into usefull folder on your server and connect it like it written in link I've provided later : )

```
<?php
    require_once("nbbc.php");
    $bbcode = new BBCode;
    print $bbcode->Parse("[i]Hello, World![/i]  This is the magic of [b]BBCode[/b]!");
?>
```

Comment: It's much better to use something newer and actively supported like my Shortcode library: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode .