# PHP regex : How to use captured groups in a function

Tags: php, regex

I'm building a hand-made function in php that searches for specific tags ( [b][/b] for bold, [i][/i] for italic and [img][/img] for pictures ) in a string, to replace them into their html equivalent. I also have to treat what's between [img] [/img] tags (can be more than one in a string) in a seperate function before the replacement, i've called it foo here :

```
<?php
function convert($txt){
    $patterns = array(  '/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/' ,
                        '/\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/' ,
                        '/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/');
    $replace = array("<b>$1</b>" , "<i>$1</i>" , foo("$1") );
    $res = preg_replace($patterns,$replace, $txt);
    return $res;
}
```

It works correctly for the b and i tags, but not img.

**The issue here is that :** When i put the captured group (referenced by "$1" i think) in a function, it treats "$1" as a string, and not what is referenced by it.
For example, if foo is declared like so :

```
function foo($var){
    echo $var;
}
```

If i put the string `text1 [img]path[/img] text2` in convert()

Then `"$1"` will be echoed, instead of `"path"`

---

**Therefore here is my question :** How can i "evaluate" the string i've captured in a different function. In the previous example, to echo in foo what is between [img][/img] tags?

Thank you for anyone taking time to reply.

Comment: Use single quotes or escape the `$` symbols. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: [Here an idea](https://tio.run/##TZDBioMwEIbveYpBCtGlVNrjttbrHnuPocR01NBoQozLwrZ9dXcqu2Vvw/cn3/yM7/w8H8rTx4mxZhp0NG4A7YZPDDFdxa@YsW8GEDBOYQAfsD0H9FZpPGtlba30NeWPSqT1zdxM32aVTDdvZVaJvNrKB1/DnzVd9RmZnjaAVS92EgroYm9Hj9ooqzsVxnQJsj3kOX0MscNAS53GcQStPJVAcA20wU0edmAaGBAveFmkvyVJsZVFkVCbBErgBxpgDLpI@GbRb3hy5PBOyQK2BI6v6JD/g3vy3tew3GHP7oyh7tzrPFyQWZpetQijm4JGkT/JGkQta2hcgNrZi8jrJzLSLMhEZY2ml5KTk5XHef4B) with `preg_replace_callback`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2082209/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/35200542/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/13047070/2943403

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70983730/2943403

Comment: There is so much relatable content on Stack Overflow that simply isn't related.  The Linked side-list is only populated after adding these comments and the Related side-list is always absolute garbage @bobblebubble  I don't think that this question Needs Focus; it seems pretty well-narrowed to me.

Comment: @Renard Do you see why it is inappropriate for `foo()` to `echo`? The function should be `return`ing a value, not echoing it.

Comment: Why don't you use a library that do bbcode to html for you? BTW, regex isn't the way to manage this. Search for tokenization.

Comment: @mickmackusa yes! i just used foo as an example. In my code it actually returns a value after having fetched something in my database with the value passed as a parameter. But the issue was the same.

Comment: @Braiam I wished i could use libraries but it's a school project and we are not allowed to use them. only raw php, which is why i'm struggling a bit! I'll try to look into tokenization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, it is strongly recommended to use a legitimate BBCode parser (library) instead of a regex approach.  A custom-developed parser should be expected to better handle fringe cases much better than a basic regex pattern.

Now that that disclaimer is given, the way to resolve your issue of calling a function from the replacement parameter of `preg_replace()` is to call `preg_replace_callback()`, or in your case, perhaps better coded via `preg_replace_callback_array()` since you are seeking different callbacks for different patterns.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aJLPV))

```
function convert(string $txt): string {
    do {
        $txt = preg_replace_callback_array(
            [
                '~\[([bi])](.*?)\[/\1]~' => fn($m) => sprintf('<%1$s>%2$s</%1$s>', $m[1], $m[2]),
                '~\[img](.*?)\[/img]~' => 'foo',
            ],
            $txt,
            -1,
            $count
        );
    } while ($count);
    return $txt;
}

function foo(array $m): string {
    return '<img src="' . $m[1] . '">';
}

echo convert("text1 [img]path/src[/img] text2 [b]bold [i]nested string[/i][/b] [img]another/path/to/file[/img] [b]nice[/b] lingering end bbtag [/b] and [b]unclosed");
```

Output:

```
text1 <img src="path/src"> text2 <b>bold <i>nested string</i></b> <img src="another/path/to/file"> <b>nice</b> lingering end bbtag [/b] and [b]unclosed
```

You will notice that calling `foo()` is done by using its string name as the callback value.  The matches array is sent to the custom function despite not being explicitly mentioned in the `'foo'` value.

I am calling `preg_replace_callback_array()` in a `do-while()` loop to ensure that nested bbcode tags are replaced (which otherwise would have been overlooked because their parent tag completely enclosed them).

If you wish to handle `[u]` tags, simply add `u` after `bi` in the first regex pattern.

Comment: It's a school project so we are not allowed to use libraries sadly! It's raw php only.

Comment: Kind of. Or at least it is much less obscure to me!  I looked up for preg_replace_callback related stuff and it is what i was looking for for what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: If you would like me to further explain any part of my answer, just ask.

Comment: Alright, there's one single point i'm curious about. 
So, function foo() : string { . . . } is a way to say we return a string? Is it good practice to always do that with php functions, as in indicate return type? For it is dynamically typed, I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: Yes, I highly recommend declaring the types on both the incoming arguments and the return data.

Comment: Ha! There are still people out there, that promote understanding and go into detail :) So we don't need to be desperate, as long there is someone out there teaching us to to fish.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
function convert($txt){
    $pattern = array('/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/' => function($matches) { return " 
<b>$matches[1]</b>"; },
                     '/\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/' => function($matches) { return " 
<i>$matches[1]</i>"; },
                     '/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/' => function($matches) { echo 
$matches[1]; return "<img>$matches[1]</img>"; });
    $res = preg_replace_callback_array($pattern, $txt);
    return $res;
}
$result = convert("text1 [img]path[/img] text2");
echo "\n$result\n";
```

Output:

```
path
text1 <img>path</img> text2
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it would be much better if it explained the changes it makes to the code in the question.  As someone coming in without an understanding of `preg_replace_callback_array`, it's not immediately clear what it does.  This could even be in the form of code comments explaining each step.

Comment: If who have never seen `preg_replace_callback_array`, all they have to do is open the PHP manual. Is that something a beginner can do, and Stack Overflow has to pay attention to such a basically thing?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback-array

Comment: That's true. Adding the explanation is _optional_, but it makes the answer _better_, because it spares people the time of doing that.  You could even write something as simple as "`preg_replace_callback_array` does exactly this: it takes an array of regex patterns paired with functions that return the replacement for that pattern."

Comment: This answer does not attempt to populate the `<img>` tag, it merely appends the bbcode string after it.  The `foo()` function is never called. Using a pattern delimiter other than a forward slash will cut down on some escaping inside the pattern.  Square brace array syntax and PHP7.4 arrow function syntax will cut down on some of the syntactic bloat. `$res` is an unnecessary, single-use variable declaration.

Comment: I think your obsession doesn't make sense to me, the questioner, and the other visitors, but I've revised and cleaned up the answer. How's that sound?

Comment: It is very clean, preg_replace_callback_array does seem to make everything simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the string first and then run the function:

```php
<?php
function convert($txt){
    preg_match('/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/', $txt, $match);
    $patterns = array(  '/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/' ,
                        '/\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/' ,
                        '/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/');
    $replace = array("<b>$1</b>" , "<i>$1</i>" , foo($match[1]) );
    $res = preg_replace($patterns,$replace, $txt);
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: `preg_match()` is probably not suitable because it only makes one match, but it is easily assumed that a realistic string may contain more than one img tag.

Comment: As @mickmackusa said, a string can contain multiple [img] tags.
It's on my end, as I should have specified it in my question!